FMC data transfer between 2 zynq ultrascale Boards
I am tryping to to data tranfer betwwen 2 zcu102 boards. Master zcu102 i am using processor and want to send data to slave zcu102 using FMC debug card XM105. On both FPGA I have attached ILA. I can see at master side that data is getting transferred till master XM105. However, on slave side everything is zero "0".
Can anyone help?
I tried to check the signals at XM105 with logic analyser and oscilloscope. All bits are correct but at slave side no output.
